# How to create dynamic-linq where for a List of Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I've been using dynamic-linq to filter a list of object using a simple Where clause:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Age = 0;
    public string FirstName = "";
}

var list1 = new List<Employee>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    list1.Add(new Employee()
    {
        Age = i,
        FirstName = "FirstName-" + i
    });
}
IQueryable<Employee> queryable1 = list1.AsQueryable();
IQueryable<Employee> result1 = queryable1.Where("Age==3");
```

The code above is working but now I have to apply the same logic on a List of Dictionary:

```
public class EmployeeDictionary : Dictionary<string, object>
{

}

var list2 = new List<EmployeeDictionary>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var employeeDictionary = new EmployeeDictionary();

    employeeDictionary["Age"] = i;
    employeeDictionary["FirstName"] = "FirstName-" + i;

    list2.Add(employeeDictionary);

}
IQueryable<EmployeeDictionary> queryable2 = list2.AsQueryable();
IQueryable<EmployeeDictionary> result2 = queryable2.Where("Age==3"); //ParseException raised!
IQueryable<EmployeeDictionary> result2 = queryable2.Where("Value.Age==3"); //ParseException raised!
```

I guess there must be a way to tell dynamic-linq how the list items should be cast but I'm having an hard time to find how.

**UPDATE**

I took an Employee class as an example so everyone could understand but the reason why I use a dictionary is because it will be filled from a dataReader generated from a dynamic sql query.  The where clause should also be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use dynamic linq at all, since you already have the field information in a dictionary, which doesn't use static lookups of its keys.

```
IQueryable<EmployeeDictionary> result2 = queryable2
    .Where(dictionary => object.Equals(dictionary["Age"], 3));
```

Comment: Actually, my example is a bit out of context so it could be misleading... The dictionary will be made dynamically with data taken from a dataReader (also taken from a dynamic SQL query).

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf And?  You can trivially use variables instead of constants for the dictionary key and the value to compare it with.  They don't need to be known at compile time.  All you need to know at compile time is *that it's a dictionary*.

Comment: Well, as long as I have an hardcoded criteria, it could work.... but my criteria has to be dynamic too.  Is it possible with a regular LINQ where?

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf There should be a small, finite number of operators to use, so you should be able to just use a `switch` or the morale equivalent.

Comment: I guess I could work with the *small* number of operators but not the *finite*

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf The number of operators in C# is finite.  You can't create your own operators, so we *know* that the number of possible operators is a finite list.

Comment: I fully understand @Servy, I am trying to do exactly the same thing. I have no idea at compilation time what is in that dictionary or what the filter condition will be. Everything is dynamic.
Servy, did you find a solution?